# cannot locate dynamic element after switch back to a frame

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I’m using robot framework and selenium library to automate testing a website.

I need to click menus which elements are under some frame, tests are looked like as below:

```
# switch to default content first
  unselect frame
# switch to level one menu's frame which id is head and click menu1a which id is menu1a
  select frame head
  click menu1a
# switch to level two menu's frame which id is menuFrame and click menu2a which id is menu2a
  unselect frame
  select frame menuFrame
  click menu2a
# do some testing
  …
# then I need to do some other testing in another menu
# switch to default content first
  unselect frame
# switch to level one menu's frame which id is head and click menu1b which id is menu1b
  select frame head
  click menu1b
  unselect frame
# switch to level two menu's frame which id is menuFrame and click menu2b which id is menu2b
  select frame menuFrame
  click menu2b
# do some other testing
  …
```

When execute click menu2b, selenium raise a exception: 
Element with locator 'menu2b' not found.

When click menu1a and menu1b manually, the level two menus(menu2a, menu2b) changed dynamically inside a div and under the same frame which name is menuFrame, and if I locate different level two menus under the same level one menu, it is ok, as following:

```
unselect frame
select frame head
click menu1a
unselect frame
select frame menuFrame
click menu2a
# do some testing
  …
unselect frame
select frame head
click menu1a
unselect frame
select frame menuFrame
click menu2c
# do some other testing
```

I also set selenium speed to 1 seconds which will wait 1s after executing every command, still raise exception.

**update:**

When I press F12 to find the menu2b element, the html is:

```
<li id="22" onclick="showStation(1012);"><a class="innerA" target="mainFrame" href="test.jsp">menu2b</a></li>
```

but, when I print page source when execution, the html is:

```
<li id="50" onclick="showStation(1012);"><a class="innerA" target="mainFrame" href="test.jsp">menu2b</a></li>
```

the element id is different...

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem is still unknown, may be element id is modified by javascript.
After some hours, I find a way to solve the problem, that is locate the element by text, because element text is always not change.

Comment: Or just use xpath, that is also an option.